# Do the writers of Arrow have more than a five year plan?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

So far, each season of *Arrow* has corresponded to roughly one year of time during Oliver's time away from Starling City, each five years previous to the "current" year.

Given the current pattern, season 6 would run past the available flashback years.

**Have producers/writers stated whether or not they have a plan to address this issue?**

*No, I'm not expecting a quote on a detailed plan - I'm just hoping for some sort of statement on whether not long term plans past season 5 exist or have been considered.*

Comment: Season six is when they start flashing *forward!* Then from season eleven, *sideways*. [Oh god.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(TV_series))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quick searching suggests their original plan was to end the series with [the obvious flashback](http://insidetv.ew.com/2012/07/30/arrow-cast/):

> “The last episode of the series will be [Arrow] seeing the [rescue] boat in the pilot,” said executive producer Andrew Kreisberg. “Every week is telling the origin story.”

[More recent interviews](http://www.buzzfeed.com/kateaurthur/how-arrow-finally-got-superhero-television-right#.md64ON6Ao) indicate the plan is for 5 seasons of flashbacks:

> *Arrow*, as first imagined by Berlanti — the television writer/producer behind *Everwood* and *Brothers & Sisters*, among many others — when he got an overall deal with Warner Bros. three years ago and they asked him whether he was interested in developing any DC properties, is an origins story. The show is set to run for five seasons, each flashing back to a year of Oliver’s captivity. By the end of the show, Oliver will have evolved from the Hood to the Vigilante to the Arrow — to Green Arrow.

I haven't found anything indicating a season 6 plan, but that is 2 seasons out.  Usually shows plan 1 season out at most.

Comment: For the show to survive in holywood it will have to start appealing to a younger generation. that means more crap teenybopper actors and love triangles. Arrow will have to develop a sense of humour or they get a new actor to provide comic relief. To this day I STILL dont understand how the Flash can have better ratings that The Arrow?? meh.

Comment: they can claim the show will only run for 5 years right up until season 5 is still getting awesome ratings...

Comment: "the Hood to the Vigilante to the Arrow — to Green Arrow". Then the show will be cancelled because they are out of names.